# Shallow copy a React component with a provided store in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

When I try `shallow(<LoginForm />)` I get the following error `Invariant Violation: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`. So in order to fix this, I tried:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginForm />
    </Provider>
);
```

This works, however, the debug output is:

```
<ContextProvider value={{...}}>
  <LoginForm />
</ContextProvider>
```

But I also want to render the LoginForm. Some other things I tried to get this fixed:

`wrapper.find(LoginForm).shallow();`

```
shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <LoginForm />
    </Provider>
).dive();
```

`wrapper.find(LoginForm).shallow();`

```
shallow(<LoginForm />, {
    wrappingComponent: Provider,
    wrappingComponentProps: { store }
});
```

But all of these result in the same error mentioned above. How am I able to fix this, while using the `shallow` method? Also, the `LoginForm` uses react hooks, including a `useSelect` hook, so passing a store to my component prop is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you consider using the `mount` function?

Comment: Yes, `mount` works, however, I would like a shallow render instead of a full one.

Comment: Does `shallow(<Provider store={store}><LoginForm /></Provider>).dive();` help?

Comment: Nope. Already, tried that (fixed the typo).

Answer (score 0):

You can mock useSelector, also handy mock selector function

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { getIsAuthorized } from 'modules/auth/reducer';
import SignIn from '../SignIn';

jest.mock('modules/auth/reducer');

jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  const RealModule = jest.requireActual('react-redux');
  return {
    ...RealModule,
    useSelector: (fn) => fn(),
  };
});

interface SetupProp {
  isAuthorized: boolean;
}

describe('Page: SignIn', () => {
  const setupWrapper = ({ isAuthorized }: SetupProp) => {
    (getIsAuthorized as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(isAuthorized);
    return shallow(<SignIn />);
  };

  test('should render form', () => {
    const wrapper = setupWrapper({ isAuthorized: false });
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

SignIn Component:

```
  const SignIn: FunctionComponent = () => {
   //...
       const isAuthorized = useSelector(getIsAuthorized);
   //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme actually anticipates the need for this and supports exactly what you need! The `shallow` function [supports options](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#arguments), one of which is `wrappingComponent`. Try doing something like this :

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { ThemeProvider, defaultTheme } from '../somewhere';

function shallowWithTheme(Component, options) {
  return shallow(Component, {
    wrappingComponent: ThemeProvider,
    wrappingComponentProps: { theme: defaultTheme },
    ...options,
  });
}


describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('renders and whatnot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.do.something();
  });
});
```